# Load Image Async from Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server .Net 6 app.  It has a Synfusion grid which has an ImageViewer componen that I have built.  When the grid is loaded it passes a DocumentID to the ImageViewer for each row.  The ImageViwer takes the DocumenID and loads an image via a web API service from a database.  Teh problem I have is that the image does not fully load, it works if I use the OnInitializedAsync method but thsi does not work if I filter the data.  Any ideads the best method to load such images

```
<SfGrid>
<MyImageViewer AuthCookieValue="@AuthCookieValue" DocumentID="@data.DocumentID" />
<SfGrid>
```

//THIS IS MY IMAGE CONTROL

```
@inject HttpClient httpClient

@if (DocumentFileData != null)
{
<img src="data:image;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(DocumentFileData))"  />
}


@code {
public int _DocumentID { get; set; }

[Parameter] public string AuthCookieValue { get; set; }

[Parameter] public int DocumentID
{
    get { return _DocumentID; }

    set
    {
        _DocumentID = value;

        //I know this is naughty to call a method via a property and does not work but thought I would try to trigger the change of the image when I refresh the grid 
        Task.Run(() => GetDocument());
    }
}

private byte[] DocumentFileData { get; set; }

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    //THIS METHOD WORKS BUT DOES NOT WORK WHEN I CHANGE THE GRID
    if (DocumentID != 0)
    {
        await GetDocument();
    }
}


private async Task GetDocument()
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthCookieValue);  
    MyServices.DocumentService documentService;documentService = new(httpClient);

    documentService = new(httpClient);
    DocumentModel doc = await documentService.GetDocumentAsync(_DocumentID);
    DocumentFileData = doc.FileData;

 }
}
```

[image]

Many thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work when i change the grid?"

Comment: also how you are filtering the data? can you share all of Sfgrid code

Comment: Hi @WajeehHasan
Sure - see attached pic of how my filters work.  Its effectively a form with a  button.  I hit the DB for new data based on filters, but the images are loaded when I provide them with an DocumentID by the grid.  I used this approach as I did not want to include Image binary data in the original database call.  eg my filters returns 100 cars but my grid is paged to only show 10 results.  So rather than include the image binary data in the 100 resultset.  The grid will load the image via API call for the 10 results being shown.  Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two small changes:

```cs
// //I know this is naughty to call a method via a property and does not work but thought I would try to trigger the change of the image when I refresh the grid 
//  Task.Run(() => GetDocument());
```

and

```cs
//protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
  protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
  {
```

See the [Lifecycle events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#lifecycle-events) documentation.

OnInitializedAsync() is only called once in the lifetime of a component. OnParametersSetAsync() is called each time DocumentID changes, and the side benefit is that you don't need that Task.Run() anymore.

The fact that Task.Run() was not awaited here made your UI fall out of sync and not show the image. It was being loaded but not rendered.

Comment: OMG your are an absolute star.  That worked a treat.  I didnt know there was OnParametersSetAsync event.  This is amazing.

Thanks ever so much for all your help.  Your an absolute gentleman.  Really appreciate it

Comment: Opps my bad I didnt realise you could click the tick.  All ticked and upward arrow clicked too.  Thanks once again.  Keep up the amazing work